# Google Chart : Single quote in title

Tags: encoding, google-visualization

The title of my column-chart contain a single quote. It's displayed like this: `&#39;` .

I have other specific characters, such as 'é', but they work perfectly.

I tried to URL-encode the text, without result.

Is there something I need to know about Google Visualization and single quotes?

Comment: care to share an example? seems to work here --> [https://jsfiddle.net/t16j6753/](https://jsfiddle.net/t16j6753/)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was wrong about the problem. I'm working in a Rails app, and I'm rendering my charts via Erb templates, with the title as a parameter.

Solution was to pass that parameter like this `raw(title_string)`, so the single quote character is escaped. Issue was about Erb, not Google Chart.

[WhiteHat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5090771/whitehat) comment helped me realise that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is an old question, but as I too have had this issue, with title and column values I pop in my solution.
If your title is

> title: 'my title's great'

then you need to escape the ' in the title with a backslash \ . It becomes

> title: 'my title\'s great'

If your title is

> title: "my title's "great""

then you need to escape the " in the title with a backslash \ . It becomes

> title: "my title's \"great\"".

What I have started to do is put \ before all specials.  Some systems may need to you to use double backslash in your code for the single backslash to make it to the google chart.